# Why does it complain about type {intrinsicattributes && true} or type {intrinsicattributes && false} are not assignable using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have code like below,

```
 function Parent() {
     const count1 = 2;
     const count2 = 4;
     const isCount = count1 < 0 || count2 < 0; //setting isCount here
     return show ? (
         <Dialog>
             <Body>soemthing</Body>
             <Actions
                 isAdminAndisCount={isAdminAndisCount}
             > 
                 {((isAdmin && !isCount) || !isAdmin) && (
                     <Text onClick={onHide}>Close</Text>
                 )}
                 {isAdmin ? ( //to refactor this
                     isCount ? (
                         <a href="eee">email us</a>          
                      ) : ( 
                          <a href="mmm">add</a>
                      )
                  ) : null}
              </Actions>
          </Dialog>
      ) : null; 
  }
```

this works fine but refactored this code

```
{isAdmin ? ( //to refactor this
    isCount ? (
        <a href="eee">email us</a>          
    ) : (
        <a href="mmm">add</a>
    )
) : null}

 **TO**
const RenderLink = ( isCount: boolean ) =>
    isCount ? <a href="eee">email us</a> : <a href="mmm">add</a>;

{isAdmin && <RenderLink isCount={isCount} />} //here is the error
```

But this displays link for email us even though !isCount and i see error

error "type {isCount: boolean is not assignable to type {intrinisicAttributes && false} or type 
{intrinsicAttributes && true}

Could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: `isCount` is a boolean and `intrinisicAttributes` is not a boolean. use `!!intrinisicAttributes` to turn it into boolean.

Comment: thanks but dint get it. where should i add it.

Comment: here  `<RenderLink isCount={isCount} />` how you are setting isCount value?

Comment: i have edited the question. also logging the isCount value within RenderLink component gives me object

Comment: Is this because if `isAdmin` is false, then `{isAdmin && <RenderLink isCount={isCount} />}` will be false, which is not a React component? You may try `{isAdmin ? <RenderLink isCount={isCount} /> : null}` instead.

Comment: thanks tried this and still shows the same

Comment: logging it gives me object like object  isCount: false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first arg in React functional components is their props which is an object of received props. So change this line:

```js
const RenderLink = ( isCount: boolean ) =>
```

To:

```js
interface Props {
   isCount: boolean
}
const RenderLink: React.FC<Props> = ({isCount}) =>
```

Comment: yes maybe this is the solution by Destructing  the props object.